# Update colour of Kivy Buttons when value changes

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to produce a visual representation of a production line(see attached photo). I have buttons that represent each station, when the station passes it is green when fails red. This information is gathered from a sql database.

Essentially i would like my if statements to work when the app is running.

```
class MyFloat(FloatLayout):


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyFloat, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        with self.canvas:
         



            self.button = Button(text='CG', size_hint=(1/11, 1/11), pos_hint={'x': 1/11, 'top': .5},
                                 background_color = (1,0,0) if live_check('CG') == False else (0,1,0))
            self.add_widget(self.button)



            self.button = Button(text='SB', size_hint=(1/11, 1/11), pos_hint={'x': 3/11, 'top': .5},
                                 background_color = (1,0,0) if live_check('SB') == False else (0,1,0))
            self.add_widget(self.button)


            self.button = Button(text='SH', size_hint=(1/11, 1/11), pos_hint={'x': 5/11, 'top': .5},
                                 background_color = (1,0,0) if live_check('SH') == False else (0,1,0))
            self.add_widget(self.button)



            self.button = Button(text='OS', size_hint=(1/11, 1/11), pos_hint={'x': 7/11, 'top': .5},
                                 background_color = (1,0,0) if live_check('OS') == False else (0,1,0))
            self.add_widget(self.button)



            self.button = Button(text='LB', size_hint=(1/11, 1/11), pos_hint={'x': 9/11, 'top': .5},
                                 background_color = (1,0,0) if live_check('LB') == False else (0,1,0))
            self.add_widget(self.button)

            self.button = Button(text='OCLT', size_hint=(1/11, 1/11), pos_hint={'x': 2/11, 'top': .25},
                                 background_color = (1,0,0) if live_check('OCLT') == False else (0,1,0))
            self.add_widget(self.button)


            self.button = Button(text='CCLT', size_hint=(1/11, 1/11), pos_hint={'x': 4/11, 'top': .25},
                                 background_color = (1,0,0) if live_check('CCLT') == False else (0,1,0))
            self.add_widget(self.button)




            self.button = Button(text='CT1', size_hint=(1/11, 1/11), pos_hint={'x': 6/11, 'top': .25},
                                 background_color = (1,0,0) if live_check('CT1') == False else (0,1,0))
            self.add_widget(self.button)


            self.button = Button(text='CT2', size_hint=(1/11, 1/11), pos_hint={'x': 8/11, 'top': .25},
                                 background_color = (1,0,0) if live_check('CT2') == False else (0,1,0))

            self.add_widget(self.button)

            timer = 0
            self.test = Button(text='test', size_hint=(1 / 11, 1 / 11), pos_hint={'x': 8 / 11, 'top': .75},
                                 background_color=(1, 0, 0) if timer ==0  else (0, 1, 0))

            #self.test = Callback(self.my_callback)

            self.add_widget(self.test)

            for i in range(0, 12):
                print(i)
                timer = timer + 1
            print('timer= ',timer)











class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
       return MyFloat()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: attached photo :   https://imgur.com/bj6wF2S

Comment: Please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) addressing your main problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you use logic in python, it is evaluated when that code is executed, and has no effect when the `if` condition changes after that.

To get your desired results typically, you would use a kivy `Property` that you can use to bind actions (like changing background color). Even easier is to use those `Properties` in a `kv` file, where the required bindings are automatically set up. Then, when a `Property` changes, the `if` code is re-evaluated.

For example, if you define a `DictProperty` in your `MyFloat` class:

```
class MyFloat(FloatLayout):
    abba = DictProperty({'CG': True, 'SB': True})
```

Then you can reference it in `kv`:

```
background_color: (1,0,0) if root.abba['CG'] == False else (0,1,0))
```

Then changing `root.abba['CG']` to `False` will change the `background_color`.

If it is more convenient, you can define the `Property` in the `App` class instead, then in the `kv` you would reference it as `app.abba['CG']`